# Is there a way to serialize a class(object) as a nested object in a serializer?

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a couple of classes that I would like to attach to my model class as nested objects in Django Rest Framework. I have tried 'helping it' figure how to serialize my classes with **repr**() and all to no luck. Is there a way to actually nest my custom classes into model representation as read only objects?

```
class WorkflowAction(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.code = None
        self.name = None
        self.context = None
        self.state_from = None
        self.state_to = None
        self.permission_class = None


class WorkflowDefinition(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.has_workflow_definition = False
        self.has_workflow = False
        self.workflow_actions = WorkflowAction()
        self._obj = obj

    def __repr__(self):
        _dict = {}
        for item in filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_') and not callable(getattr(self, x)), dir(self)):
            _dict[item] = getattr(self, item)
        return str(_dict)
```

The classes are attached to model objects as property:

```
@property
    def workflow_definition(self):
        return WorkflowDefinition(self)
```

The model serializer & view are vanilla:

```
class RiskShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Risk
        fields = (
            'id',
            'project',
            'summary',
            'description',
            'workflow_definition'
        )

class RiskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Risk.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RiskShortSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the nested serializer and add it as an explicit field in `RiskShortSerializer`